# BusterJS and Sinon, spies don't reset

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, buster.js

Is there a way to reset a spy for every spec in a buster test case. I'm aware of `spy.restore` but I'm looking for a behavior like in Jasmine where spies automatically reset after every spec.

Comment: Where do you instatiate the spies? I think they shoud be defined inside of a test and thus cannot keep ant states between specs.

Comment: I creates them in the `before` function

Comment: in that case i think you will have to reset them in the after or the before as well.